# UIWebview: loading pdf locally has image containing pink border around it

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

[image]

When loading a locally stored PDF file, a pink rectangular box is found around the images. These are not links but yet they are sorrounded by a pink rectangular window. when viewed through PREVIEW in mac this seems to be working absolutely fine.